# Why is the destructor of child class called before parent‘s’?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

in C++, when the object's desctructor is called, it first invokes child class's destructor, and then parent's, which is the opposite of construct procedure.
But why? It seems to be a simple question, but I haven't found a satisfying answer on the internet. Could someone explain the nessisity of doing destructing in such sequence?

Comment: How else could it work? A derived object cannot exist unless its base object exists in a valid state. This means the derived object must be constructed *after* the base, and destructed *before* it.

Comment: @dxiv what if parent's destructor  is called first?  Why does the base object need to exsit in a valid state in destructing procedure?

Comment: Because it couldn't possibly work otherwise. Any derived class member function, including the constructors and destructors, can access base class members at any time, which requires the base object to exist in a valid state at that point.

Comment: @dxiv but any base class function could be virtual function, which could also access child member in destructor procedure.

Comment: No. When the destructor of the base class executes, the type of the object is no longer the derived type, but the base type. No virtual call gets "dispatched" to derived classes, but instead must be resolved in the base type. Same goes for the constructor of the base class, except the type of the object is not *yet* the derived type.

Comment: @scottxiao Re _"...virtual function..."_ see __During construction and destruction__ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual _"...In other words, during construction or destruction, the more-derived classes do not exist...."_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about parent/child meaning inheritance consider that

```
 struct Car : Vehicle { ... };
```

is not really much different than

```
 struct Car { Vehicle _base; ... };
```

except that automatically when you refer to a `Vehicle` property in a `Car` method `_base.` is implicitly added by the compiler.

The standard even calls this the "base class sub-object"... it's an object that has no name and that you use implicitly, but it's still there.

Now in C++ members of a class are constructed before the class itself, and destroyed after. The same happens to the implicit "base class sub-object". So when building a car you need first to build the vehicle... and after destroying the car all individual members are destroyed, including the vehicle.

Comment: Nice answer, which analyze the problem from a new point.

Comment: but why not destroy members before destroying the car? Just as you refered, the task of child destructor is to call member's destructor. Then why not destroy the base sub-object first.

Comment: @scottxiao: member are initialized before `Car::Car` starts because the constructor of `Car` is dealing with (sort of) a `Car` object and you can call `Car` methods; symmetrically the destructor is called first (when all members are still valid) because destructor code will execute in a (being dismantled) `Car` object. What happens is more complex if you end up calling methods of `Car` during the construction of `Car` members... also something often forgot is that in case of an exception during `Car::Car`, code in `Car::~Car` is NOT run (destructor is started only if constructor completed).

Answer (score 6):

Since this was tagged [language-lawyer], this is the rule that says what a destructor does:

> [class.dtor]
>
> After executing the body of the destructor and destroying any objects with automatic storage duration allocated within the body, a destructor for class X calls the destructors for X's direct non-variant non-static data members, the destructors for X's non-virtual direct base classes and, if X is the most derived class ([class.base.init]), its destructor calls the destructors for X's virtual base classes.
> All destructors are called as if they were referenced with a qualified name, that is, ignoring any possible virtual overriding destructors in more derived classes.
> Bases and members are destroyed in the reverse order of the completion of their constructor (see [class.base.init]).

Why?... It just makes sense. Things that are constructed in one order are generally destroyed in the opposite order. This convention applies to sub objects of classes, as well as elements of arrays, local variables in a function as well as objects with static storage duration destroyed at the end of the program. I cannot think of anything where this isn't the case.

Although dependencies between objects within their lifetime can be two-directional, during the construction and destruction the dependency can only be in one direction. Object that is created *before* cannot depend - within its constructor - on an object that is created later (because that object doesn't exist yet). Same applies to destruction but in reverse: An object that is destroyed *later* cannot depend - within its destructor - on an object destroyed *before* (because that object doesn't exist anymore).

If you can depend on something within your construction, then you will typically expect to be able to depend on that something within the destruction. In other words, you would expect the direction of dependency to remain in the same direction. The inverse destruction order satisfies this expectation.

To return to the c/d-tors, constructor body is the last thing to execute in the constructor, so the destructor body should be the first thing to execute in the destructor. And it will be useful in some cases to be able to use the base sub object within destructor body, which wouldn't be possible if it had already been destroyed.

---

> Why does the base object need to exsit in a valid state in destructing procedure?

To understand this, it should help to think about why the destructor body exists in the first place. Typically, it is to change the internal state of the class in preparation for ending the lifetime. A typically familiar action is deletion of an owning pointer stored as a member (this is just an example: use smart pointers instead). If the object no longer exists in a valid state, then it would be too late to touch that now-invalid state.

---

> but any base class function could be virtual function, which could also access child member in destructor procedure.

Virtual function calls resolve to the current class during destruction (just like during construction).